# Objective c simple sorting using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: xcode

I want to simple sorting in nslog , this is my viewcontroller.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
sobj=[[SortObjects alloc]init];

sobj.description;  //this doesn't work

[sobj description];//this doesn't work either

NSLog(@"sobj = %@", sobj);
```

}`

& here is my Object Class SortObjects.h

```
enter code here- (NSString *)description {
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.lastName];
NSArray *firstNames = @[ @"Alice", @"Bob", @"Charlie", @"Quentin" ];
NSArray *lastNames = @[ @"Smith", @"Jones", @"Smith", @"Alberts" ];
NSArray *ages = @[ @24, @27, @33, @31 ];

NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray array];
[firstNames enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    SortObjects *sObjects = [[SortObjects alloc] init];
    sObjects.firstName = [firstNames objectAtIndex:idx];
    sObjects.lastName = [lastNames objectAtIndex:idx];
    sObjects.age = [ages objectAtIndex:idx];
    [people addObject:sObjects];
}];

NSSortDescriptor *firstNameSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstName"
                                                                          ascending:YES
                                                                           selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
NSSortDescriptor *lastNameSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastName"
                                                                         ascending:YES
                                                                          selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
NSSortDescriptor *ageSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"age"
                                                                    ascending:NO];

NSLog(@"By age: %@", [people sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ageSortDescriptor]]);
```

value of sobj is coming null in nslog??

Comment: You return `self.firstName, self.lastName` from `description` which is not set at that moment. So you get `"<null> <null>"`.

Comment: @vadian is right regarding the Null Value,  You want to store sorted value of all type(name,lastname and age) in your model object. Can you confirm you.

Comment: so what to do next for result?